# Domdocument AppendChid

Tags: php, html, formatting, domdocument, appendchild

I`m using this routine:

```
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $row['body']);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $as = $dom->getElementsBytagName('a');
    //if anchor exists
    if($as->length)
    {
        foreach ($as as $a)
        {
            //get parrent af anchor 
            $a_parent = $a->parentNode;
            //create h4 element
            $h4 = $dom->createElement('h4');
            //append a to h4
            $h4->appendChild($a);
            //append h4 to anchor parent
            $a_parent->appendChild($h4);    
        }
        $body = $dom->saveHTML();
```

to find all `a` tags in a html string such as this :

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and 
typesetting<a href="#">foo</a> industry.</p>
```

and wrap the `a` tags with an `h4` tag. When I execute myscript the result was malformed and the output is:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
typesetting industry.<h4><a href="#">foo</a></h4></p>
```

but I want this format :

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
and typesetting<h4><a href="#">foo</a></h4> industry.</p>
```

any suggestions please.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to stop using @ to suppress errors. It isn't good practice.

Comment: @vascowhite No Errors Found !

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand... what you're saying is that you want a space between `</h4>` and `</p>`?

Comment: @AndrésGattinoni Updated, check the question again

Comment: @AndrésGattinoni Position of `h4` and `a` was changed and it appended in end of parent but i just want to prevent changing the position of `h4` and `a`.

Comment: I'm still not following you... is it that you're losing some other HTML that should be between `</h4>` and `</p>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use replaceChild() ? Here, your code modified. Couldn't try it, but should work.

```
   $dom = new DomDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $row['body']);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $as = $dom->getElementsBytagName('a');
    //if anchor exists
    if($as->length)
    {
        foreach ($as as $a)
        {
            //get parrent af anchor 
            $a_parent = $a->parentNode;
            //create h4 element
            $h4 = $dom->createElement('h4');
            //append a to h4
            $clone = $a->cloneNode();
            $h4->appendChild($clone);
            //append h4 to anchor parent
            $a_parent->replaceChild($h4, $a);
        }
        $body = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error'  DOMNode->replaceChild(Object(DOMElement), Object(DOMElement)) #1

Comment: When we executing $h4->appendChild($a) , the $a was removed from parent node and appended to $h4 we must find a solution to replace without removing $a!

Comment: Tanks , but the output is : `<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and 
typesetting<a href="#"></a>foo industry.</p>` its mean that the value of anchors was cloned! the links converted to : `<a href="#"></a>foo` !

Comment: **Updated :** Just insert `$clone->nodeValue = $a->nodeValue;` after $clone. it's works fine for me. Thanks.

Comment: oh, you could also use $a->cloneNode(true) to indicate deep cloning. Meaning that you want everything inside the <a>.